# Get row number using where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

// Table

```
+------+-------+
| user | score |
+------+-------+
|   2  |  500  |
|   3  |  780  |
|   4  |  50   |
|   5  |  250  |
|   6  |  650  |
+------+-------+
```

// Current sql

```
SELECT @rn:=@rn+1 AS rank, user, score
FROM (
  SELECT user,score
  FROM scores
   WHERE user = 2
  ORDER BY score DESC
) t1, (SELECT @rn:=0) t2
```

The above sql return that user with id = 2 have a rank = 1, but rank is 3. Is correct when where clause is not added. But i want to be able to search for e specific user and get his rank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
select * from
(SELECT @rn:=@rn+1 AS rank, user, score
  FROM scores,
  (SELECT @rn:=0) t2
ORDER BY score DESC) t
where user=2
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e22cb1/9)

Comment: Btw is there a faster way?

Comment: you are using mysql only rite??